# What type is <?> when making instantiating lists?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have seen in multiple different places people who instantiate a list or ArrayList like:

```
List<?> l = new ArrayList<>();
```

What type is ?? Does this mean that it can hold any types in it? If so, why would this be used instead of just and ArrayList?

Comment: You can only insert `null` into a `List<?>`, as per the [Java Tutorial on Unbounded Wildcards](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/unboundedWildcards.html)

Answer (score 9):

> Does this mean that it can hold any types in it?

No. It means that your `l` variable could be referring to a list parameterized with any type. So it's actually a *restriction*: you will not be allowed to add any object to `l` because you have no idea which items it accepts. To give a concrete example, `l` could be a `List<String>` or it could be a `List<ExecutorService>`.

Comment: So, it can only hold one type, which you don't know what it is. If I am understanding you correctly, why would this be of any use to anybody? I can't really see a reason.

Comment: It's very useful in a method signature. Say, `boolean hasPrimeNumberOfItems(List<?> list)`---if you couldn't specify the wildcard, you couldn't declare the signature to be as general as you want.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik how is that different from `<T> method(List<T> list) `? I'm sorry if the syntax is a bit off, I don't use java, but I'm sure you get the point of my question.

Comment: @dcastro It becomes different when you involve `T` somewhere else in the signature as well.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Can you provide a concrete example of something that could not be done using a simple named type parameter? I'm sorry, but the `hasPrimeNumberOfItems` example did not convince me.

Comment: @dcastro You mean, `?` is a redundant feature of the language? BTW `hasPrimeNumberOfItems` is by no means aimed to demonstrate what you ask.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I'm not saying that, I'm sure it's not. I'm really just looking for a scenario where it's needed. Even though I'm not familiar with Java, these things interest me.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik If the `hasPrimeNumberOfItems` example wasn't aimed to demonstrate a situation where `?` is needed, then why did you state that "if you couldn't specify the wildcard, you couldn't declare the signature to be as general as you want."?

Comment: Then consider `Class<?> Object.getClass()`. This cannot be replaced by `<T> Class<T> Object.getClass()` because `T` is not inferrable.

Comment: @dcastro What I said was aimed to help OP, not you, and he has a completely different angle on the question.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I see, thanks for the example. The problem there is that `Object` does not know what type `T` will be for the derived classes, so it uses a wildcard instead. In other languages, this type of issue is usually solved using F-bound polymorphism. But that technique wouldn't fit here and would overcomplicate type definitions. C#, on the other hand, has the `object.GetType` method which simply returns a non-generic [`Type`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type(v=vs.110).aspx) instance.

Comment: @dcastro "Overcomplicate" is a severe understatement: it would require Object to be a parameterized type and require each Java class to explicitly extend Object providing itself as the type parameter. And that means that it would break backwards compatibility of the complete JDK.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Agreed 100%. Perhaps I should have said "it would wreck the entire type system" lol.

Comment: @dcastro - wildcard, or use-site variance, is great for naturally invariant types, like `Class<T>` and `List<T>`. that's a great choice in Java 5. But now, in Java 8, we are dealing more with naturally variant types, like `Function`. it's no longer a great choice:) Frankly it sucks:)

Comment: @bayou.io Can use-site and declaration-site be married? Could Java get a consistent feature to do that? So far I think it could. Existing use-site bounds could be intersected with declaration-site bounds. Most would thus become redundant and new code could skip them.

Comment: I guess there has to be a new syntax at use-site  e.g. `Function?<A,B>`, which is equivalent to `Function<? super ...>`, based on declared variance of type parameters.

Comment: @bayou.io Yeah, it's great to see Java moving in the right direction. Marko: I just learned Scala has a really cool way of solving the F-bound polymorphism problem. You can just declare the return type as `this.type`, e.g. `trait Interface { def f: this.type }`. [This trick](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/architecture-of-scala-collections.html) is used to implement Scala's awesome collections library, such that every collection automatically inherits a `map` method that returns a new collection of the *same* type: `list.map(_ + 1)` returns a list, and `set.map(_ +1)` returns a set.

Answer (score 1):

As correctly pointed by Marko, its an unknown restriction on the List type.

The Java docs says that:

> The unbounded wildcard type is specified using the wildcard character
>   (?), for example, `List<?>`. This is called a list of unknown type.
>   There are two scenarios where an unbounded wildcard is a useful
>   approach:
>
> - If you are writing a method that can be implemented using    functionality provided in the Object class.
> - When the code is using methods in the generic class that don't depend    on the type parameter. For example, List.size or List.clear.
>     In fact,    `Class<?>` is so often used because most of the methods in
>     Class do    not depend on T.

Comment: Just try it: `List<?> a = new ArrayList<Integer>(); a.add(1);` and then compare the outcome with your opening statement.

Answer (score 1):

Let me make this a long bed time story; read it to fall asleep:)

---

Let's begin with this point -- To invoke a generic method, its type arguments *must* be supplied. (Unless the method is invoked in a "raw" manner, i.e. in the erased form, which is another topic:)

For example, to invoke `Collections.<T>emptyList()`, `T` must be supplied. It can be supplied explicitly by the programmer --

```
List<String> list = Collections.<String>emptyList();  // T=String
```

But that is tedious, and kind of dumb. Obviously in this context, `T` can only be `String`. It's stupid if the programmer has to repeat the obvious.

That's where *type inference* is helpful. We can omit the type argument, and the compiler can infer what the programmer intends it to be

```
List<String> list = Collections.emptyList();  // T=String is implied
```

Remember, `<String>` is still supplied, by the programmer, implicitly.

---

Supposedly, the programmer is the all-knowing dictator of all type arguments, and, the compiler and the programmer have a common understanding on when type arguments can be omitted and inferable from context. When the programmer omits a type argument, he knows the compiler can infer it exactly as he intended, based on a rigorous algorithm (which he masters:)
It is not the compiler's discretion to pick and choose type arguments, rather, the programmer does, and conveys it to the compiler.

Realistically, type inference is so complex, <s>few</s> no programmer has any idea what's going on in a lot of cases:) The programmer is more like a dictator making vague commands, and the compiler tries its best to make sense out of it. We mostly write code on intuition, not paying attention to details, and we sort of believe that the code does what we want if the compiler approves it.

In any case, all type arguments are fixed precisely and predictably at compile time. Any omitted type argument is equivalent to an explicitly specified one.

Some type arguments are "undenotable", e.g. a type variable introduced by capture conversion. They can not be explicitly specified, they can only be inferred. (Nevertheless the programmer is supposed to know what they are, even though they cannot be named)

---

In the previous example, `T` can only be inferred as `String`, there's no other choices. But in a lot of cases, there are more candidates for `T`, and the type inference algorithm must have a strategy to resolve it to one of the candidates. For example, consider this lonely statement

```
    Collections.emptyList();
```

`T` could be any type; `T` is resolved to `Object`, because, well, there's no good reason to resolve it to anything else, like `Integer` or `String` etc. `Object` is more special because it's the supertype of all.

---

Now, let's get to constructors. Formally speaking, constructors are not methods. But they are very much alike in a lot of aspects. Particularly, type inference on constructors is almost the same as on methods. Invoking a constructor of a class CLASS takes the form of `new CLASS(args)`.

Just like methods, a constructor can be generic, with its own type parameters. For example,

```
class Bar
{
    <T>Bar(T x){ .. }
```

and type inference works on generic constructors too

```
    new Bar("abc");  // inferred: T=String
```

To explicitly supply type arguments for a constructor,

```
    new <String>Bar("abc");
```

It's pretty rare though that a constructor is generic.

---

A generic constructor is different from a generic CLASS! Consider this

```
class Foo<T>
{
    Foo(T x){ .. }
```

The class is generic, the constructor is not. To invoke the constructor for class `Foo<String>`, we do

```
    new Foo<String>("");   // CLASS = Foo<String>
```

Method type inference we've been talking about so far does not apply here, because the constructor is not even generic. In Java 5/6, there is no type inference on CLASS, therefore `<String>` must be explicitly specified. It's stupid, because `<String>` is obvious in this context. There were workarounds (i.e. using static factory methods), but people were of course very upset and demanded a solution.

---

In Java 7, this problem is solved by "diamond inference" -

```
    new Foo<>("");   // inferred: T=String
```

"diamond" refers to the curious `<>` operator. It is required; we cannot simply write

```
     new Foo("");
```

because that already had a different meaning - invoking the constructor of "raw" `Foo`.

With diamond inference, we can do things we couldn't in Java 5/6

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();  // Java 7. inferred: E=Object
// equivalent to
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>(); // <Object> is required in Java 5/6
```

Remember, `T=Object` is still supplied, through diamond inference.

---

Finally, we come back to your original question

```
List<?> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Here, `E=Object` is inferred (what else?). The code is equivalent to

```
List<?> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

Yep, the `list` object is indeed an `ArrayList<Object>`, not `ArrayList<SomethingElse>`.

Also note that the following would be illegal and nonsensical

```
List<?> list = new ArrayList<?>();
                            ^^^
```

`CLASS` in `new CLASS(args)` must be a concrete type. We can only instantiate an `ArrayList` of a specific element type.

---

The declared type `List<?>` of variable `list` is too general though. For a local variable, it is the best practice IMO to declare it in its more specific type

```
ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Don't use `<?>` here - it just causes confusion to everybody.

On a related note, a lot of people would argue for "program against interface"

```
     List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
     ^^^^
```

That is wrong IMO. Who are we providing abstraction for in a local block? Use the most specific type in implementation for max clarity;
use abstract types in interfaces.

---

zzzzzzzzzz

Comment: when both class and constructor are generic - http://stackoverflow.com/a/32304725/2158288