# Why is it wrong to supply type parameter in the constructor of a generic class (Java)?

Tags: java, oop, generics, syntax, constructor

I'm just learning about generics in Java from a textbook, where it talks about a class `GenericStack<E>` implemented with an `ArrayList<E>`.

Since in order to create a stack of strings, you use

```
GenericStack<String> = new GenericStack<String>()
```

or

```
GenericStack<String> new GenericStack<>()
```

therefore shouldn't the constructor of
`GenericStack` be defined as `public GenericStack<E>()`, or `public GenericStack<>()`? The answer is no. It should be defined as `public GenericStack()`.

Why is this? Obviously the constructor can easily infer the type from the class declaration, but given the verbosity of Java, I'm a bit befuddled why the `<E>` or simply the `<>` formalism is completely gotten rid of here.

Comment: Go to understand java genric again. <E> can be used around whole class which contains many methods. Constructor is one of the methods, it may uses <E> or not.

Answer (score 7):

There are two parts to this:

1. The generic type parameter given for the class definition is available within the class itself.
2. You can have generic types specific to individual methods (including constructor).

Look at the following example:

```
package snippet;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Y<E> extends ArrayList<E> {

    public <T> Y(T t) {
    }
}
```

Where as the type `E` is available to the whole of the class, the type `T` is valid only within the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing a method's declaration with its call site (that is, where you use it). If you want to use a generic that's declared on the class, only ever need to provide the `<E>` or `<>` at the call site — *not* the declaration. And in that regard, a constructor is declared like any other method:

```
public GenericStack<E> {
    public E get() { ...            // correct
    public <E> put(E element) { ... // bad (see below)
    public GenericStack() { ...     // correct, like the get()
```

Redeclaring the generic (as in the `put` case above) actually *shadows* it; the `E` in `put(E)` is actually a different `E` than in `GenericStack<E>`, despite having the same name. This is confusing, and you should avoid doing it.

Comment: I noticed that all of the new posted Q&A belongs to topic java were downvoted. It's weird. Maybe someone intended.

Comment: @J.Lyu Do you have other examples of this happening? I checked a couple posts and didn't see it.

Comment: just my guess. No example for now. Most of those are upvoted again. When you search 'java' you may see most of the questions got negative vote.  Maybe they are actually not good.

Comment: OP already knows what you have stated: _Obviously the constructor can easily infer the type from the class declaration_

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Well, I was talking about the declaration site, not the call site. But I could have been clearer about that; edited it.

Comment: OP is asking, syntactically, why Java doesn't use `public GenericStack<E>() {...}` or something similar for its constructor declarations. They know that the type variable is in scope in the constructor declaration and body. I don't see the relevance of type shadowing. The generic constructor answer is much more convincing.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis ::shrug:: I think I've answered that, but you're of course free to disagree and not upvote (or even downvote, I guess, though I don't think it deserves that).

Answer (score 1):

Both the class and the constructor can be generic on their own, i.e. each has its own type parameters. For example

```
class A<T>
{
    <S>A(S s){}
}
```

To invoke the constructor with all explicit type arguments

```
new <String>A<Integer>("abc");  // T=Integer, S=String
```

Think of it like this, `A<Integer>` is the concrete class, and `<String>A` is the concrete constructor.

Because of type inference, we can omit the type argument for the constructor

```
new A<Integer>("abc");  // S=String is inferred
```

The type argument for the class can also be omitted and inferred, by "diamond" (`<>`) syntax

```
A<Integer> a = new A<>("abc");  // T=Integer is inferred, as well as S=String
```

I wrote a (long) post on this subject - https://stackoverflow.com/a/32292707/2158288