# Can I make a constructor generic without making the class generic?

Tags: java

I have seen in Java that one can make a Class generic and a method generic. I have also seen codes that make the constructor generic along with the Class. Can I make only the constructor generic? And if yes, how to call the constructor?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32304427/why-is-it-wrong-to-supply-type-parameter-in-the-constructor-of-a-generic-class/32304725#32304725

Comment: While it is possible I am more interested why do you want to create generic constructor to non-generic class. Or more generally, why is such constructor is possible.

Comment: @Pshemo - constructor is just like a method, so why can't it be generic?:)

Comment: @bayou.io But what could be the purpose of having generic type unrelated to class? I though about scenario where we want to create class to store pair of elements so their type should also match but `public <T> Pair(T t1, T t2)` will also accept `new Pair("", 1);` since `T` will be replaced by most common type (like Object).

Comment: @Pshemo It makes no sense to me either. What's ever weirder is that you can supply a type argument when the constructor isn't even generic. `Integer a = new<String>Integer(42);`

Comment: example in JDK - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/management/StandardMBean.html#StandardMBean%28T,%20java.lang.Class%29

Comment: @PaulBoddington OK, I found one reason. Lets say that we want our class to accept object of type which is combination of other types (class & interface). We can't use `SomeClass(Type1 & Type2 value)` but we can use `<T extends Type1 & Type2> SomeClass(T value)` (`Type2` must be interface).

Comment: @PaulBoddington - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28014853/what-is-the-point-of-allowing-type-witnesses-on-all-method-calls

Comment: @bayou.io Thanks, that are very interesting links. Today I've learned something new :D

Comment: @Pshemo That's a good example, although you could see it as a limitation of the type system. If `Type1 & Type2` were a type you could write `SomeClass(Type1 & Type2 object)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can.

```
class Example {

    public <T> Example(T t) {}

    public static void main(String[] args){

        // In this example the type can be inferred, so new Example("foo") 
        // works, but here is the syntax just to show you the general case.
        Example example = new<String>Example("foo");
    }
}
```

Comment: @Birendra I wasn't sure either. I knew it was possible though and after a bit of experimentation I managed it! I've never ever seen a reason for doing this though.

Comment: you can also write `new Example("foo")`